# React Navigation v5 options / setOptions as functions

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

So the docs for React-Navigation V5 says that in order to add options to a `Screen` you have to access do the following syntax

```
<SettingsStack.Navigator>
  <SettingsStack.Screen
    name="B"
    component={B}
    options={{ tabBarLabel: 'Settings!' }}
  />
<SettingsStack.Navigator />
```

The `options` is an object, my question would be, could it work if i tried to make it as a function, same goes for the `setOptions` method on the navigation, it has to be passed like

It would help me in de-duplicating code, for example

```
navigation.setOptions({
    headerLeft: () => Platform.select({
      ios: (
        <NavigationHeader.TextButton
          label={t('general.cancel')}
          onPress={navigation.pop(1)} //duplicated
        />
      ),
      android: (
        <NavigationHeader.IconButton
          iconName="times"
          label={t('general.cancel')}
          onPress={navigation.pop(1)} //duplicated 
        />
      )
    })
  });
```

I'm writing the same thing twice in the onPress

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function that takes a function as a parameter that specifies what you would want to do on click for the headerLeft button. Then inside that function you can return a function that returns your headerLeft component:

```
function leftButton(clickHandler) {
  return () =>
    Platform.select({
      ios: (
        <NavigationHeader.TextButton
          label={t('general.cancel')}
          onPress={clickHandler}
        />
      ),
      android: (
        <NavigationHeader.IconButton
          iconName="times"
          label={t('general.cancel')}
          onPress={clickHandler}
        />
      ),
    });
}

// ...

navigation.setOptions({
  headerLeft: leftButton(() => {
    navigation.pop(1);
  }),
});
```

`leftButton` is an example of a higher order function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function.

So this way you can adjust the clickHandler in one place and the `onPress` gets updated for both buttons.